# show and hide fields according to dropdown list in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I had achieved it, but I deleted the code by mistake... with the following example it would help me to show 2 states.

> ```
> import React, { useState } from 'react';
>
> export default () => {
>   const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
>
>   return (
>     <>
>       <button
>         type="button"
>         onClick={() => {
>           setShow(!show);
>         }}
>       >
>         Mostrar {show ? 'Div 2' : 'Div 1'}
>       </button>
>
>       {show ? (
>         <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>Div 1</div>
>       ) : (
>         <div style={{ color: 'blue' }}>Div 2</div>
>       )}
>     </>
>   );
> };
> ```

But I have a dropdown list with four options, and depending on which one I select, it will show different fields on the form.

> ```
> import "./styles.css";
> import React, {useState} from "react";
>
> export default function App() {
>   
> const [animal, setAnimal] = useState(null);
>
>   
>
>   return (
>     <div className="App">
>       <>
>       <div>
>       <label htmlFor="tipoId" className="col-md-6">
>       Select Animal
>       </label>
>       <select onClick={() => setAnimal(!animal)}>
>         <option value="0" selected hidden>Horse</option>
>         <option value="1" selected>Tiger</option>
>         <option value="2">Lion</option>
>         <option value="3">Panther</option>
>       </select>
>       </div>
>       
>      {
>       animal === "1" ? 
>          <> <div> TIGER</div> </> 
>       : animal === "2" ? (
>         <> <div>LION</div> </>
>       ): (
>         <> <div>PANTHER</div> </>
>       )
>     }
>  </>
> </div>
> ```
>
> ); }

As you can see, the current code does not work, since it will only allow to have 2 states, show by default the panther ones and if another option is selected it will only show the tiger one, but the lion fields are never shown. Previously I had even been able to include in the drop-down list to be able to choose 6 options and that when choosing these they would show fields for this respective option.

I need to get to that point again :(

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: 176 / 5.000
Resultados de traducción
Thanks for your interest, improve the question. And it is that I need a drop-down list to have 5 options, when choosing one of these that shows different content for each option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use `switch` case instead of `if` or `ternary operator` because you have multiple conditions to check.
See below code I have added a separate function `getAnimalDiv` which will be responsible for returning `div` depending on the selected `option`.
and when you set state `animal` instead of using `!animal` set it to `event.target.value` so that you will actually get selected value in the state.
and if you do `!animal` it will set only `true` and `false` which is not useful in this scenario.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

    const [animal, setAnimal] = useState(null);

    function getAnimalDiv(){
        switch(animal){
            case "0":
                return <div>TIGER</div>;
            case "1":
                return <div>LION</div>;
            case "2":
                return <div>PANTHER</div>;
            case "3":
                return <div>Other option</div>;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="tipoId" className="col-md-6">
                        Select Animal
                    </label>
                    <select 
                    onClick={(event) => {
                        // here set target value to state which is 0, 1, 2, 3
                        setAnimal(event.target.value);
                    }}>
                        <option value="0" selected hidden>Horse</option>
                        <option value="1" selected>Tiger</option>
                        <option value="2">Lion</option>
                        <option value="3">Panther</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                {getAnimalDiv()}
            </>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it fulfills the functionality that I need. I am going to apply it to the form, I hope there is no news.